# Always show scrollbars with iScroll

Tags: javascript, css, ios, scroll

Is it possible to always show the scroll bar in iScroll

Currently iScroll is working beautifully on a div with overflow:scroll.. however due to the content the user sees there is no way for them to know that there is more in the div

For this reason it would be much better to show the scroll bar on the side showed permanently so that users understood the limits to the content

**vScrollbar: true** doesn't seem to work

EDIT:
This question is specifically to do with using iScroll (http://cubiq.org/iscroll) for touch devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still looking for an answer to this, I think what you do is look for this line of code on line 78:

```
hideScrollbar: isIDevice,
```

And just comment it out (//) or delete it. That's what I've done and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 11):

Just add `hideScrollbar:false` to the options list.

Worked just fine for me, using iScroll4.

Cheers

Comment: this is the better answer. editing the source library seems wrong to me

Comment: Thank you! I also think it's wrong. I always try not to edit the source code.

Comment: http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/src/iscroll.js (V4)

what to use on version 5?, http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/build/iscroll.js

Comment: @Jaider, Sorry; I did not update my apps for v5 yet. But I'll give it a try and let you know if I solve it before you do.

Comment: @fledgling No. I couldn't. I believe use another lib instead.

Comment: @Jaider Can you please recommend me any lib ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a fixed height to the div that will have a scroll bar and put your content in a div inside this one with a min-height higher than the fixed height of the parent div... that should make the scroll bar always visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/5gT2U/

Comment: Thanks but your solution is only for native scrollbars. iScroll is used  to give scrollbars to touch devices like 'android's browser' or 'io's safari' these do not have a scroll bar so iScroll creates the effect with javascript. see here: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Answer (score 0):

For iScroll version 5 please set the below options

```
var myScroll = new IScroll('#demo', {
    scrollbars: true,
    fadeScrollbars: true
});
```